# How to make pop-up div hide/show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a button to change and make div pop-up after clicked and after being again clicked hide div and came back to normal. How do I do that? *(also if you can keep it HTML and `css` because I am learning Java and not so familiar and good with it but if it is only way you know with Java no problem)*. I tried it with a Focus in `css` but after I click any were in a screen button  just came back to normal.

If you know this please answer it would be very big help.

```css
.viewgames {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: -5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.75 s;
}

.gamesvp {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.viewgames: hover.gamesvp {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.viewgames: hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 4px white solid;
  color: white;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.hidegames {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.viewgames: focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: -5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.viewgames: focus.gamesvp {
  opacity: 0;
}

.viewgames: focus.hidegames {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="viewgames"><p class="gamesvp">View Games</p>
```

This is what I have so far!

Comment: You need javascript for event driven dynamic behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to SO! first you want popup on full screen if yes how to again click button as its behind and not possible until you click on close button in popup and second you need some script to trigger event

Answer (score 0):

> What i had understand so far by your question this is what you want

It uses `JS`

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
 $(".popup").toggleClass('active');
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
.popup.active{
color: red;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Can i replace span with div or something also is there any way to make text or button change when clicked and get back to normal when a another button or text is clicked. Also when i run script in stackoverflow it prints this Error:{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: @Roko update my answer and error is you didn't include `JS` in head Or add from left panel drop-down of libraries